# Unable to generalize code of speedometer

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

Below code work on only in device width range  width > 400 to width<550 but not other devices like Tab( width> 550).How I can generalize

```
speedo_meter = getImage(R.drawable.newmagnetometer_final_480);
center_wheel = getImage(R.drawable.center_wheel480);
needle = getImage(R.drawable.arrow480);
canvas.drawBitmap(speedo_meter, (canvas.getWidth() / 2)- speedo_meter.getWidth() / 2,      (canvas.getHeight() / 2)- speedo_meter.getHeight() / 2, null);


// Main Meter Needle

matrix_needle = new Matrix();
 matrix_needle.setTranslate((canvas.getWidth() / 2)- needle.getWidth() ,(canvas.getHeight() / 2)- needle.getHeight());
matrix_needle.postRotate(angle_of_deviation,canvas.getWidth() / 2, 2 * needle.getHeight() - 10);
canvas.drawBitmap(needle, matrix_needle, paint_needle);

// Main Meter Wheel
canvas.drawBitmap(center_wheel, (canvas.getWidth() / 2)- center_wheel.getWidth() / 2,       (canvas.getHeight() / 2)- center_wheel.getHeight() / 2, null);
```

Uploaded image captured on Tab
[image: I want create code for device independent I create code but it work on particular height and width devices but not on all like Tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code like

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    canvas.drawBitmap(speedo_meter, (canvas.getWidth() / 2)- speedo_meter.getWidth() / 2,
             (canvas.getHeight() / 3)- speedo_meter.getHeight() / 2, null);


        // Main Meter Needle
        matrix_needle = new Matrix();
        matrix_needle.setTranslate((canvas.getWidth() / 2)- needle.getWidth() / 2,
                (canvas.getHeight() / 3)- needle.getHeight());


        matrix_needle.postRotate(110,
                canvas.getWidth() / 2, (canvas.getHeight() /(float)2.9));

        canvas.drawBitmap(needle, matrix_needle, paint_needle);

}
```

Just change Images with respective Device Width and Height.